# DataTables - how do you set a default value for lengthMenu?

Tags: jquery, datatables

DataTables allows you to change the options in the dropdown menu for number of records shown per page: https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu

However, if you define it as per the example:

```
"lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ]
```

You will get a default option of 10, because this appears first in the array.

What if you want to use something else (e.g. 50 or 75) as the default option? I can't see any method on their documentation that allows this. I understand you could use jquery to target by element value, but that seems like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Can you try this ? :)

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just read the bit on the link which says "Note that the pageLength property will be automatically set to the first value given in this array, unless pageLength is also provided.". Long day :)

Answer (score -2):

If you use old DataTables version:
Set default value:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": 50
  } );
} )
```

source: http://datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayLength

Comment: Wrong, and you're looking at the legacy documentation.